# Main content is not responsive when app draw closes

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am having a issue where the main content is not responsive when I close the `app-drawer`.

In [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/levemu/1/edit?html,output), when I close the door the `main content` will not move to the left. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is the expected behavior. As per the [code](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/blob/master/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html#L230-L242) of `app-drawer-layout` drawer will either stack on top of main content if narrow or the main content will have a margin equal to the width of drawer.

```
         if (this.narrow || !drawer) {
        contentContainer.style.marginLeft = '';
        contentContainer.style.marginRight = '';
      } else {
        var drawerWidth = drawer.getWidth();
        if (drawer.position == 'right') {
          contentContainer.style.marginLeft = '';
          contentContainer.style.marginRight = drawerWidth + 'px';
        } else {
          contentContainer.style.marginLeft = drawerWidth + 'px';
          contentContainer.style.marginRight = '';
        }
      }
```

Even the demos created by Polymer team seems to follow this pattern

Comment: This is not correct behavior. With the option to keep the drawer fixed, the main content can not center according to the space the drawer takes.

Comment: When you say `correct` do you mean `expected` or `should not be like this`?

Comment: If the author allows the drawer to be fixed with no overlay, then that drawer is permanent and should calculated according to the normal flow(which it is not since the main content is not centered in accordance to the drawer on the left). I am not sure if this was intentional by the author or not. So, it may be both `unexpected` and  `should not be like this`